# Wordle: Best Play to keep Average Down Given Five Possible Solutions

Tags: probability

Suppose the following situation in Wordle.  Please allow me to assume you know the rules.

You play the word SALET
You get SAL all green and ET both gray.
You deduce that there are five possible answers:

SALAD

SALSA

SALVO

SALON

SALLY

(And for the sake of this discussion, please assume that only these five are possible solutions. There are some other rare words possible, but Wordle does not use rare words as solutions nor simple plurals with S on the end, etc.)

Two Questions:

1. In regular mode (where you can play any acceptable word next), if you are after the lowest average score in your play, what should be your next play?

(I will withhold my answer for now.)

2. In hard mode, (where you must play one of the five words) what should a reasonable player, one who wants to keep his average the lowest possible, average in such a situation?

(My guess is 3.2.  But I am not sure.)

Comment: Is "VOIDY" a word? :)  Okay, for regular play DOVEY.  If it SALAD the D is yellow rest grey, SALSA all grey, SALVO the O and V are yellow, SALON just the O is yellow, and SALLY the Y is green.  3 moves.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you've narrowed down the final two letters to the set `DNOVY`.

In regular mode, play any word that matches 4 of the given letters (I can't find one with all 5).  For example, DOWNY, ENVOY, or SYNOD.

Suppose that you play DOWNY.  Then the possible outcomes all produce different letter highlighting:

- gray + gray + gray + gray + yellow = SALAD
- gray + gray + gray + gray + gray = SALSA
- gray + yellow + gray + gray + gray = SALVO
- gray + yellow + gray + yellow + gray = SALON
- gray + gray + gray + gray + green = SALLY

So you now have enough information to find the word.  Exactly **3** guesses are required: SALET, DOWNY, and then the correct word.

In hard mode, *don't* pick SALLY, as that will give you no additional information if it isn't the correct word.  Otherwise:

- If you guess the correct word, you win.
- If you get one yellow and one gray, then you know the correct word:

  - If you picked either SALAD or SALSA, and get a yellow A, pick the other word.
  - If you picked either SALVO or SALON, and get a yellow O, pick the other word.
- Otherwise, you narrow it down to three choices, in which case you can apply the previous point about SALAD/SALSA and SALVO/SALON being paired words.

  - SALAD → SALVO, SALON, or SALLY
  - SALSA → SALVO, SALON, or SALLY
  - SALVO → SALAD, SALSA, or SALLY
  - SALON → SALAD, SALSA, or SALLY

So, here's a strategy to minimize the number of guesses:

- Pick SALAD.

  - If you get a yellow A, pick SALSA.
  - If you get two grays, pick SALVO.

    - If you get a yellow O, pick SALON.
    - Otherwise, pick SALLY.

The possible sequences of guesses are thus:

- SALET, SALAD = 2
- SALET, SALAD, SALSA = 3
- SALET, SALAD, SALVO = 3
- SALET, SALAD, SALVO, SALON = 4
- SALET, SALAD, SALVO, SALLY = 4

For an expected **3.2** guesses (so, you estimated correctly), and a maximum of **4**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, my thoughts exactly.  Do not play SALLY second, of course.

However, I had LOCAL as a second play (which works all the same).

I had a different method of coming up with 3.2, however, which wasn't as elegant as yours.  I grouped the words into two groups of two as you did with SALLY as a separate group.

I thought if the answer is SALAD, you would average 2.5 half of the time and 3.5 for the other half.  So, your average is 3.  This is obviously true for the other three non-SALLY words.  And if the answer is SALLY, you would always get it in 4.  Since it is a 20% chance it is any of the five words: (3+3+3+3+4)/5 = 3.2.

By the way, I can't find a website that actually has a smart Wordle computer.  They all seem rather ignorant of strategy like this.